# Arraylist shows empty after adding items

Tags: android, json, arraylist

I have an arraylist, which i used to store json parsed values.but after adding values to arraylist it shows its size as 1.i've attached my code below.pls help me to solve this

---

```
public void completed(JSONObject jsonObject) {


        login_data = new ArrayList<Login_modal>();


        try {
            String response=jsonObject.toString();
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject res = result.getJSONObject(RES);
            String stat = res.getString(STAT);
            String username = res.getString(USERNAME);
            String useremail = res.getString(USEREMAIL);
            String userId = res.getString(USERID);
            String userAvatarFile = res.getString(USERAVATARFILE);
            String userType = res.getString(USERTYPE);
            String authID = res.getString(AUTHID);
            String cntr = res.getString(CNTR);
            String loggedInOnce = res.getString(LOGGEDINONCE);
            String topicarn = res.getString(TOPICARN);

            Login_modal login_details = new Login_modal(stat, username, useremail, userId, userAvatarFile, userType, authID, cntr, loggedInOnce, topicarn);

            login_details.setStat(STAT);
            login_details.setUsername(USERNAME);
            login_details.setUseremail(USEREMAIL);
            login_details.setUserId(USERID);
            login_details.setUserAvatarFile(USERAVATARFILE);
            login_details.setUserType(USERTYPE);
            login_details.setAuthID(AUTHID);
            login_details.setCntr(CNTR);
            login_details.setLoggedInOnce(LOGGEDINONCE);
            login_details.setTopicarn(TOPICARN);

            login_data.add(login_details);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

---

here is my json file

---

```
{
  "res": {
    "stat": "SUCCESS",
    "username": "Aggie",
    "useremail": "aggie@logicalsteps.net",
    "userId": "u55e29ddfe7cbd",
    "userAvatarFile": "",
    "userType": "SUB",
    "authID": "",
    "cntr": "",
    "loggedInOnce": "",
    "topicarn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:080141827424:Demogroup"
  }
}
```

---

here i am getting arraylist

---

```
 if(login_data.get(1).equals("SUCCESS")) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login failed try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

---

error log

---

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
                                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
```

---

Comment: check size of `login_data`, are you getting size>0?

Comment: _to arraylist it shows its size as 1_  Size of 1 is not empty (as the title of your question claims). In any case, you should avoid this line `login_data.get(1)`, if you haven't checked size first. This may be the cause of the exception.

Comment: i've added 10 items into arraylist and while debugging it gets arraysize as 1.i need to get it as 10.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing wrong. correct way is

```
 if(login_data.get(0).getStat().equals("SUCCESS"))
```

your `login_data` has only 1 record so you will get this by `get(0)` **0:index(first element)**

```
login_data.get(0) ---->  return Login_modal at 0 position

login_data.get(0).getStat() ----> return Stat of  Login_modal at 0 position
```

Comment: @MuhammedRiyasAV check `(login_data.get(0).getStat()) == SUCCESS` or not

Answer (score 0):

Arraylist index starts with 0 and you are using login_data.get(1) and the arraylist size only 1

```
if(login_data.get(0).equals("SUCCESS")) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login failed try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Your JSON response keys are in lower case but you are pasring in UPPER case

for example you should parse like this for the rest:

```
 String stat = res.getString("stat");
```

You already created constructor and again you are using setter method. I'm assuming that in LOGIN_MODEL constructor you are setting every variable.
comment these lines

```
            login_details.setStat(STAT);
            login_details.setUsername(USERNAME);
            login_details.setUseremail(USEREMAIL);
            login_details.setUserId(USERID);
            login_details.setUserAvatarFile(USERAVATARFILE);
            login_details.setUserType(USERTYPE);
            login_details.setAuthID(AUTHID);
            login_details.setCntr(CNTR);
            login_details.setLoggedInOnce(LOGGEDINONCE);
            login_details.setTopicarn(TOPICARN);
```

Comment: even if i use  if(login_data.get(0).getStat().equals("SUCCESS")) ,it gets only else part

Comment: @MuhammedRiyasAV Anytime

Answer (score 0):

common man its typo error. You are passing your json key in arrayList

```
login_details.setStat(STAT);
```

It should be

```
login_details.setStat(stat);
```

because you have stored value in `stat` not in `STAT`, `STAT` is your JSON key.

And one more point, your arraylist is having only 1 record so instead of `login_data.get(1)` you need to use `login_data.get(0)`

```
if(login_data.get(0).getStat().equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You added only one data.

login_data.add(login_details);

The following is not adding data to the list
 login_details.setStat(STAT);
 login_details.setUsername(USERNAME);
...
you are setting the value of the properties of the Login_modal modal instance login_details.

and then adding that one Login_modal instance to login_data.
so you will really end up with one.

Here you get exception (Index out of bounds) because you are accessing the 2nd (index 1; 1st is index 0) element of login_data which does not exist.
 if(login_data.get(1).equals("SUCCESS")) {